# Moving object through nodes in Quadtree

Tags: physics

I'm working on my own quadtree for use in games for physics (collision detection to be exact) but am unable to move an object from one node to another node.

What I'm doing is if some object is to be moved, I'm deleting it from its old position and adding a new object (with same property, such as width and height) to the new position. Is my approach correct or is there any other optimized process to do same?

The problem I'm facing is that if I move an object from node 0 to node 3 (both node being children of, for ex., root node) the root node container(I'm using std::vector) gets the object but it is not updated in the node 3's container.

Any solution to my problem? Though would be happy to try some other method too.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be working with references (or pointers depending on your language) ... moving something should almost never require one object to be destroyed and another created.

Comment: As an example [Double Linked Lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list) use pointers to the next an previous objects in the list so you can interchange them easily, this comes with it's own disadvantages though, like not being able to directly access an element.

Comment: Well I'm programming in C++ and using pointers for nodes, the prob I'm having is updating the child nodes with the (moved) object though. Anyways giving it a try again, without deleting the obj, like you said.

Comment: Just to be clear, you will still have to remove the object from the prior node ... but since you're using pointers you can just zero/null out that pointer rather than killing the underlying object :-)